# How to shift x-axis right/left when resizing a ZedGraph chart? 

Tags: zedgraph

I display a stock price chart with ZedGraph, hence using the `Y2Axis` and `XAxis`. When I **resize by dragging the mouse** in the right corners, or the right edge of form, I would like the left side of **XAxis to shift along with the resize**, such that the bar width and bar spacing remain constant. So a drag should make me see more or less candlesticks, instead of expanding or compacting the bars. How do I achieve this? 
(In the Y-direction it's OK, as it auto-scales, which is fine).

BTW, I use mostly intraday time frames, so the bar interval may be anything from 1 min up to daily or weekly bars.

---

EDIT: 
OK.. I fixed it by manually coding the `scale.min/max` on the resize event. I don't think there are auto-settings that gives this behavior.

Comment: Why are you operating on Y2 axis? have you seen http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Open-High-Low-Close_Demo

Comment: Hi Gacek, 
Financial charts are typically viewed with a right-side axis, as it shows price at the current/last bar.  Or... maybe I have misunderstood; I thought YAxis was left side, and Y2Axis right side.. Or can they be shifted?

Comment: ..
I guess I could handle the resize event and calculate and update the Scale.Min.. But I thought maybe it was some inbuilt setting that could "unfix" the XAxis.scale.min and instead rely on bar spacing value and Scale.max (?)
..yes thanks, I saw this example, but as far as I could see, it is no advanced scaling there, so it would not work well on dynamic data as it is.

Comment: Yes, you are right. YAxis is always located on the left side. But still, Y2 should also autoscale correctly, something went wrong. Can you post some code?

Comment: I added some code, and found a "half-way" solution. Although it still got some fine-tuning as I questioned above, and not sure if it's the easiest way to solve it (?)

Comment: Oh.. I see the way I calculate the scale.min is the reason for inconsistent bar size on low scale. As I use left/right of form as reference. i need to find pixel position of last bar instead, and also "estimate" position of the first (to the left) bar, then use that range as the reference for calc..  hmm..

Comment: Ok, Thanks Gacek, but I got it working now :) 
..unless you know some different solution to what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by manually coding the scale.min/max on the resize event. I don't think there are auto-settings that gives this behavior.